# Delete data in attachment field

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a local table with an attachment field.  I have tried deleting with vba and manually and the previous attachments keep coming back.  In vba I have tried it with a recordset and with SQL.
The SQL

```
Let strSQL = "DELETE tblSpecsPics.PicID,tblSpecsPics.SpecID,tblSpecsPics.SpecDetailID,tblSpecsPics.PicNum,tblSpecsPics.Pic.FileData,tblSpecsPics.Pic.FileName,tblSpecsPics.Pic.FileType,tblSpecsPics.ImageDesc FROM tblSpecsPics;"

db.Execute strSQL, dbSeeChanges
```

The recordset

```
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblSpecsPics WHERE Not (tblSpecsPics.Pic.FileData) Is Null;", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

If Not rst.BOF And Not rst.EOF Then
rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
    rst.Edit
    Set rsv = rst.Fields(4).Value
    rsv.Delete
    rst.Update
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

End If

When I add new records the old attachments reappear without fail.

Comment: You don't "delete" a field in a record - you set its value to null.  Delete is for full records only.

Comment: Actually @TimWilliams, attachment types in MS Access tables are really join tables with pointer to main table. To remove all meta data, one must delete the underlying linked records.

Comment: @Parfait - thanks for the correction: that's a new one for me.

Answer (score 4):

Because MS Access Attachment Types are actually linked tables of meta data (*filename, filedata, fileflag, filetype,* etc.), you need to delete these underlying linked records. So consider nesting another recordset loop on the attachment field value from main table:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblSpecsPics WHERE Not (tblSpecsPics.Pic.FileData) Is Null;"

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

If Not rst.BOF And Not rst.EOF Then
    rst.MoveFirst
End If

Do Until rst.EOF

    Set childrst = rst.Fields(4).Value
    Do Until childrst.EOF
       childrst.Delete
       childrst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: I did the same thing with the SQL statement (posted) that I executed, but I tried your idea with the recordset.  I still have the problem the attachments do not delete.  I can delete everything and it will appear to be deleted but as soon as I try to load new attachments the old attachments reappear as if they were never deleted.  The old attachments have a different file location than the new .  If I step through the code the only attachment that shows in the variables is the new attachment, but when I look at the table the old attachment has reappeared.  This is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot recreate your *reappearing* issue. To be sure, i just re-ran this code. I added two attachments to an attachment field (from different folders) across three records. Ran my posted code here and ALL attachments from ALL records were removed. And when going to add new attachments, no previous ones appeared. How are you *loading*? From form or table?

Comment: It is loading attachments from a file in a folder.  It seems to only be with certain attachments that are loaded.  Any others are deleted if I use the SQL statement or the recordset.

Comment: My question is *how* are you loading? Directly using table or on a developed form? See bottom of [MS article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-d40a09ad-a753-4a14-9161-7f15baad6dbd#bm9) for supported types.

Comment: The attachments are loaded to a table using vba.  The attachments can viewed on a form and are included in reports.  There is not a problem with the supported types.  The attachments show on the form and the report as they should.  The problem has been deleting and that is only happening with certain attachments.  I can tell when it will happen.  I can look at the access file size after deleting all attachments and doing compact and repair.  The access file will be larger  matching the size of the attachments that should have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the update method unnecessary. Also, for clarity, I start at the end of the attachments and move back as it was less than obvious if the delete/next would skip every other record.

`Private Sub TestThis_Click()`

On Error GoTo errHandler
Dim rs1Count As Integer
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset2
Dim strSql As String
Dim db As Database
rs1Count = 0
Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
strSql = "SELECT T_Vendor_Complaint_A.[F_VCN_A], T_Vendor_Complaint_A.[F_Attachments_A] FROM T_Vendor_Complaint_A WHERE T_Vendor_Complaint_A.[F_VCN_A] = 271"
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)
rs1.MoveLast
MsgBox ("rs1.RecordCount:" & rs1.RecordCount & " in T_Vendor_Complaint_A VCN:" & rs1![F_VCN_A])
Set rs2 = rs1!F_Attachments_A.value
If rs2.RecordCount > 0 Then
rs2.MoveLast
Do Until rs2.RecordCount = 0
rs2.Delete
rs2.MovePrevious
Loop
End If
errExit:
Exit Sub

errHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
Exit Sub

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public Sub RemoveAttachments()
On Error GoTo SP_FjernNNDok_Err
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstAttachment As DAO.Recordset2
Dim SQL As String
Dim RecordsetCount As Integer
Dim rstAttCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim RecordNumber As Integer
Dim AttachmentNumber As Integer
RecordNumber = 1
AttachmentNumber = 1
SQL = "Your Query as string”
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
rstMedlemsCount = 0
rstAttCount = 0
rstMedlemsCount = rst.RecordCount
If RecordsetCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "There are no records with attched files"
Else
rst.MoveFirst
    Set rstAttachment = rst.Fields(2).Value ’count columnnumber in the query starting with 0 from the left side
    rstAttCount = rstAttachment.RecordCount
    While Not rstAttachment.EOF
        For i = 1 To rstAttCount
            rstAttachment.Delete
            rstAttachment.MoveNext
            AttachmentNumber = AttachmentNumber + 1
            i = i + 1
            RecordNumber = RecordNumber + 1
        Next i
    Wend
End If
    MsgBox rstMedlemsCount & " Contained attached files which were deleted."
Set rst = Nothing
Set rstAttachment = Nothing
RemoveAttachments_Exit:
    Exit Sub
RemoveAttachments_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume RemoveAttachments_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```